# How can I set NSUserDefaults for an iOS app through the command line in xcodebuild?

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, nsuserdefaults, xcodebuild

For starters, I've been through most similar questions on StackOverflow and it seems to me that almost every suggestion doesn't  work. My issue is simple:

- I want to pass "-Foo::Bar" as a key-value pair from the `xcodebuild` command line to be used via my iOS App or its `XCTest` Unit Test target. I would therefore like Bar to be returned when I do:

`NSLog(@"Foo Value: %@",
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Foo"]);`

I've tried the following till now:

`xcodebuild test -project Foo.xcodeproj -scheme FooTests -Foo=Bar
xcodebuild test -project Foo.xcodeproj -scheme FooTests -Foo Bar
-Foo=Bar xcodebuild test -project Foo.xcodeproj -scheme FooTests`

And in none of the cases did the aforementioned `NSUserDefaults` check return `Bar`. I also printed our the `NSUserDefaults` and did not see the value set. Is it possible to set `NSUserDefaults` with `xcodebuild`? What is the correct way to do this?